# Error 'Camera Cancelled' - App Sencha with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, camera, sencha-touch-2

I'm developping an app that you take pictures with phone and send to social networks.
My App is developped with sencha touch 2 and Phonegap.
When i try take a picture my app restarts and give me a error 'Camera cancelled'.
I try see console.logs but they don't appear...

Here's my code:

```
function uploadPhoto(data){
                // this is where i will send the image file to server
                //output image to screen 
                    console.log(data);
                }
    function fail(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, fail, {
                    quality : 30,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL 
                });</i>
```

Answer (score 3):

Same error here. I'm using cordova v2.6 for Android.

To solve it I had to edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` and change the DroidGap activity launch mode from "singleInstance" to "standard".

Comment: I already to this, but doesn't work :'( I am 2 mounths on this...fff...uck!

Comment: There is a section at the bottom of the document: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android wich is titled "In addition to this, if you are using camera, you will want to implement this as well:" ... maybe this helps?

Answer (score 1):

I almost got crazy with this.

You must to be pretty sure what options* are you using and passing to $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options*). For example, you'll get failure if you are using saveToPhotoAlbum (true or false), you will get always "camera cancelled" because Android doesnt have this option. Don't use this on your config on android.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of phonegap are you using? I tried using 2.7.0 here and it works without problems.

Comment: I tried phonegap 2.3.0 and now i have tried 2.6.0 and no success! I'll try now 2.7.0 if works...

Comment: I tried with 2.7.0 and nothing! I tested in my phone and gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to the AndroidManifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.PictureCallback" />
```