# Phonegap Camera LaunchMode conflict

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I have a problem with Phonegap Launch mode. This is the situation:

1. If launch mode is `singleTop` or `Standard` the camera time stamp does not work, but pushplugin works. Photo is saved to correct Camera folder
2. If Launch mode is `singleInstance`, the Camera Time stamp Works, but photo is saved to SD card (camera folder), the pushplugin does not open the App when the notification is clicked.

Not sure if that is something wrong with my `config.xml`. That if other people can get pushplugin to work on `singleInstance` as well.

Edit
I contacted Phonegap people, and they said it is because their Plugin library might not be updated. And have to use the cordova's library. I tested on IOS it has no problem, only on Android the problem appears.

Comment: Read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16298909/1761793) and its comments. You might find something.

Comment: Hi Thanks, doesnt seem to be related too much, the camera doesnt restarts the app just the time stamp isnt correct.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, the phonegap build's version is out of date, use the Cordova version. If you use the Cordova version instead of Phonegap build one then the timestamp will be correct.